# Bokeh plot zoom in/out for VBox(ts1, ts2, ts3)

Tags: python, bokeh

I am using Bokeh to plot my data points. I have 3 different charts stacked vertically one on top of another using `VBox(ts1, ts2, ts3)`.

I have mouse scroll zoom in/out working individually for each plot. I want to make sure if I can tie them together such that if I zoom in/out in one of the plots the other 2 plots also zoom in/out accordingly such that the at any point my `x` axis of all 3 charts are aligned the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a toy program that does what you want. It uses linked x and y ranges, which means not only zooming, but also panning is kept in sync.  You can see how it is done by looking at how x_range and y_range are specified in the second and third plot.

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import *

output_file('linked_panning.html')

N=300
x = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, N)
y1 = np.sin(x)
y2 = np.cos(x)
y3 = np.sin(x) + np.cos(x)

s1 = figure(plot_width=350, plot_height=350)
s1.scatter(x, y1)

s2 = figure(plot_width=350, plot_height=250, x_range=s1.x_range, y_range=s1.y_range)
s2.scatter(x, y2)

s3 = figure(plot_width=350, plot_height=350, x_range=s1.x_range, y_range=s1.y_range)
s3.scatter(x, y3)

p = gridplot(([[s1, s2, s3]]))
show(p)
```

Adapted from the bokeh example gallery file "linked_panning.ipynb"